# Measure of a Particular measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to find two measurable sets A and B such that $\mu (A+B)>0$ but $\mu (A)=0$ and also $\mu (B)=0$. The text book hint says that consider A=$C$ and B=$C/2$. But I do not understand how to calculate measure of A+B or at least show that it is greater than 0. If anyone can give a hint on how to start of, it would be great. Thanks.

Definition of A+B=$\{x=x_1+x_2:x_1\in A \hspace{1mm}and\hspace{1mm} x_2\in B\}$

Comment: What is $A+B$?  Are you working in some vector space (such as $\mathbb{R})$ and intend $A+B=\{a+b\vert a\in A \wedge b\in B\}$?  And can $\mu$ be any measure, or is it some particular measure (such as the Lebesgue measure)?

Comment: @Unwisdom edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements of the cantor set $\mathcal{C}$ can be written in ternary as $0.d_1d_2d_3d_4\ldots$, where $d_1, d_2, d_3, \ldots \in \{0,2\}$.
Elements of $\mathcal{C} \, /\,  2$ can therefore be written as $0.d_1d_2d_3d_4\ldots$, where $d_1, d_2, d_3, \ldots \in \{0,1\}$.
Now show that for any $x \in [0,1]$,
adding an element of $\mathcal{C}$ to an element of $\mathcal{C} \,/ \, 2$, we can come up with the ternary expansion for $x$.
We can also use $\mathcal{C} \,/ \, 2 + \mathcal{C} \,/ \, 2$
to the same effect.

**Edit:** More precisely:

- $\mathcal{C}\,/\,2 + \mathcal{C} \,/\, 2 = [0,1]$.

  If $x = 0.x_1x_2x_3\ldots$ in ternary, write each digit $x_n$ as $a_n + b_n$, with the following rules: $0 = 0 + 0$, $1 = 0 + 1$, and $2 = 1 + 1$.
  Then if $a = 0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ and $b = 0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots$, we have $x = a + b$ and $a, b \in \mathcal{C} \, / \, 2$.
  Also note that $1 = .222\ldots\;$.
- $\mathcal{C}\,/\,2 + \mathcal{C} = \left[0, \frac{3}{2}\right]$.

  Any $x \in \left[0, \frac{3}{2}\right]$
  can be written as either
  $x = 0.x_1x_2x_3\ldots$
  or $x = 0.x_1x_2x_3\ldots + \frac12$,
  where $x_n \in \{0,1,2\}$.
  Then notice that
  $\frac12 = .111\ldots$,
  so in the second case, we can let $y_n = x_n + 1$ and we have
  $x = 0.y_1y_2y_3 \ldots$ with $y_n \in \{1,2,3\}$.
  (Of course this is no longer a bona fide ternary expansion,
  but rather a convergent series of digits $y_n$ divided by $3^n$.)
  In either case, we have a representation
  $$
  x = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{y_n}{3^n} ,\quad y_n \in \{0,1,2,3\}
  $$

  Then let $y_n = a_n + b_n$ with the rules $3 = 2 + 1, 2 = 2 + 0, 1 = 0 + 1, 0 = 0 + 0$.
  If $a = 0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ and $b = 0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots$, we have $x = a + b$, $a \in \mathcal{C}$, and $b \in \mathcal{C} \, / \, 2$.

Comment: can we find the exact measure of the set?

Comment: @user129901 Good question.  If we had used $\mathcal{C}\,/\,2 + \mathcal{C} \,/\, 2$ instead, the resulting set would have been $[0,1]$ which has measure $1$.  But I am not sure about $\mathcal{C} + \mathcal{C}\,/\,2$.

Comment: The exact measure of $\mathcal{C} + \mathcal{C}/2$ is $3/2$, not $4/3$ as I erroneously said in my comment.  (See the edit to my answer.)